# Объединить значения в массиве php и создать новый

Tags: php, массивы, arraylist, объединение

Подскажите как решить данную проблему:

Есть массив полученный из БД:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> array(14) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["userHash"]=> string(3) "apple" ["serviceType"]=> string(2) "11" ["prise"]=> string(1) "300"}
[1]=> array(14) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["userHash"]=> string(3) "pear" ["serviceType"]=> string(1) "5" ["prise"]=> string(1) "20" } 
[2]=> array(14) { ["id"]=> string(1) "2" ["userHash"]=> string(3) "apple" ["serviceType"]=> string(2) "12" ["prise"]=> string(1) "200"}
}
```

Как внутри этого массива узнать, есть ли повторные значения (в данном примере это apple), и дальше создать новый массив, куда записать все уникальные значение, а также оставить только один apple с объединенной ценой 500 и дополнеными значенияю в `serviceType` (положить туда значения из обоих массивов), чтобы получилось так:

```
  array(2) { 
    [0]=> array(14) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["userHash"]=> string(3) "apple" ["serviceType"]=> string(5) "11, 12" ["prise"]=> string(1) "500"}
[1]=> array(14) { ["id"]=> string(1) "5" ["userHash"]=> string(3) "pear" ["serviceType"]=> string(1) "5" ["prise"]=> string(1) "20" }
```

}

Если делать в цикле, то все значения сравниваются сами с собой, что не решает проблему.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, логику кода или пример функции, чтобы решить данную задачу?

Comment: A `select sum() ... group by field`?

Comment: Не совсем корректно задал вопрос. Сейчас уточнил его. Нужно не только сложить значения какого-либо столбца, но и добавить значения из дубликата в новый.

Comment: `group_concat` для mysql, `string_agg` для postgres.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо) Пометь свой коммент, как ответ на вопрос. Я отмечу его.

Comment: Можешь и сам ответить и отметить, это работает.

Answer (score 2):

попробуй использовать GROUP BY в своем запросе к базе данных. Тем самым ты исключишь повторения столбцов